# javascript function not visible? does not get called a second time

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, backbone.js, raphael

This may be a pretty newbie question so bear with me. I am tinkering a little with Ruby on Rails 4, Javascript and Raphael. I'm using Backbone too. On my root page I got two buttons, one which renders some stuff with Raphael and another one which is supposed to do the same after changing a related parameter.

In my `application.js` I got the following:

```
var app = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
  app.paper = Raphael("canvas", 1000,700); // canvas: html div
  ...
  app.Room = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
  }
  app.RoomList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Room
  });
  ...
  app.drawRoom = function(room, x, y, z) {
    ...
  }
  ...
});
```

Upon clicking the first button, a `.js.erb` view kicks in and calls the following:

```
// retrieve data, stuff it into app.roomList, then this:
app.drawRoom(app.roomList.first(), 500, 300, 0);
```

This works as expected and renders a few circles and stuff. There's something more going behind the scenes (the rooms data is retrieved as a json from a different project's CDO server via RabbitMQ, but it's totally unrelated). Now, when I click the second button, I'm doing the following:

```
app.paper.clear();
app.drawRoom(app.roomList.first(), 800, 300, 1);
```

As you can see, my intention is to clean the canvas and redraw everything with different parameters. The new parameters are OK, and I've checked that the following works when pressing the second button, effectivaly leaving the canvas clean except for a lonely circle:

```
app.paper.clear();
app.paper.circle(222, 333, 15);
```

So I'm pretty certain it must be something related to my ignorance of javascript. I am also positive that the second call to `app.drawRoom()` is not executed, I tested it with Firebug. Perhaps some visibility issue? Thanks in advance!! Edit: The HTML for the buttons:

```
= form_tag( show_rooms_url, remote: true) do
  = submit_tag "show rooms"
= form_tag( up_level_url, remote: true) do
  = submit_tag "+1"
```

Which with `routes.rb` they are linked to 2 separate controller's methods:

```
def show_rooms
    conn = Bunny.new(:automatically_recover => false)
    conn.start

    ch = conn.create_channel

    client   = ApplicationHelper::RPCClient.new(ch, "rpc_queue")
    response = client.call("list_rooms")
    ch.close
    conn.close
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render partial: "show_rooms", locals: { response: response } }
    end
end

def up_level
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render partial: "up_level" }
    end
end
```

Then the views cointain the following calls (the same, actually, just different parameters):

```
app.drawRoom(app.roomList.first(), 500, 300, 0);
```

The generated HTML for the buttons is:

```
<form method="post" data-remote="true" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://localhost:3000/show_rooms">
  <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
  <input type="submit" value="show rooms" name="commit">
```

and:

```
<form method="post" data-remote="true" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://localhost:3000/up_level">
  <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
  <input type="submit" value="+1" name="commit">
```

Also, the drawRoom method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
....
app.drawRoom = function(room, x, y, z) {
    if (room.get('drawn') == false) {
        room.set('drawn', true);
        if (app.level === z) {
            c = app.paper.circle(x, y, 15);
            c.attr("fill", "red");
        }

        if (room.get('n') !== "") {
            if (app.level === z) {
                app.paper.path(['M', x - 10, y - 10, 'Q', x - 20, y - 25, x - 10, y - 40]);
            }
            app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('n') })[0], x, y - 50, z);
        }
        if (room.get('e') !== "") {
            if (app.level === z) {
                app.paper.path(['M', x + 10, y - 10, 'Q', x + 25, y - 20, x + 40, y - 10]);
            }
            app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('e') })[0], x + 50, y, z);
        }
        if (room.get('s') !== "") {
            if (app.level === z) {
                app.paper.path(['M', x + 10, y + 10, 'Q', x + 20, y + 25, x + 10, y + 40]);
            }
            app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('s') })[0], x, y + 50, z);
        }
        if (room.get('w') !== "") {
            if (app.level === z) {
                app.paper.path(['M', x - 10, y + 10, 'Q', x - 25, y + 20, x - 40, y + 10]);
            }
            app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('w') })[0], x - 50, y, z);

        }
        if (room.get('u') !== "") {
            app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('u') })[0], x, y, z + 1);
        }
        if (room.get('d') !== "") {
            app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('d') })[0], x, y, z - 1);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Please post the JS code that retrieves the data from RabbitMQ

Comment: definitely not related. Forget I mentioned anything about RabbitMQ - the data pops up there magically (:

Comment: Are you able to get the RabbitMQ data in your UI code?

Comment: yep. rabbitmq retrieves the data and I display it on the canvas. I never call rabbitmq again. The data is still there (stuffed into a backbone model/collection) and my only problem is the app.drawRoom() function not getting called a second time with different parameters. Sorry, this is not a rabbitmq question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt at drawing anything is failing because the `drawn` variable on your Backbone model has been set to true. The below code specifies ***not*** to draw if that particular property is true:

```
if (room.get('drawn') == false) {
    room.set('drawn', true);

    // your room drawing code is here

}
```

If you'd like to keep your boolean *drawn* flag, put the if-statement in its entirety at the beginning of the method, like so:

```
if (room.get('drawn') == false) {
    room.set('drawn', true);
}

// your room drawing code should be here
```

To be clear, the whole `drawRoom` method should probably look like this:

```
app.drawRoom = function(room, x, y, z) {
    if (room.get('drawn') == false) {
        room.set('drawn', true);
    }
    if (app.level === z) {
        c = app.paper.circle(x, y, 15);
        c.attr("fill", "red");
    }
    if (room.get('n') !== "") {
        if (app.level === z) {
            app.paper.path(['M', x - 10, y - 10, 'Q', x - 20, y - 25, x - 10, y - 40]);
        }
        app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('n') })[0], x, y - 50, z);
    }
    if (room.get('e') !== "") {
        if (app.level === z) {
            app.paper.path(['M', x + 10, y - 10, 'Q', x + 25, y - 20, x + 40, y - 10]);
        }
        app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('e') })[0], x + 50, y, z);
    }
    if (room.get('s') !== "") {
        if (app.level === z) {
            app.paper.path(['M', x + 10, y + 10, 'Q', x + 20, y + 25, x + 10, y + 40]);
        }
        app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('s') })[0], x, y + 50, z);
    }
    if (room.get('w') !== "") {
        if (app.level === z) {
            app.paper.path(['M', x - 10, y + 10, 'Q', x - 25, y + 20, x - 40, y + 10]);
        }
        app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('w') })[0], x - 50, y, z);

    }
    if (room.get('u') !== "") {
        app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('u') })[0], x, y, z + 1);
    }
    if (room.get('d') !== "") {
        app.drawRoom(app.roomList.where({ id: room.get('d') })[0], x, y, z - 1);
    }
}
```

Also, have you attempted clearing the canvas with:

```
app.paper.clearRect( 0, 0, app.paper.width, app.paper.height )
```

I've found this to be the most effective way of doing so.